Baking in package version during export to wheel file
I have a poetry-based python project A, with the version being defined in pyproject.toml as
[tool.poetry]
name = "Project A"
version = "1.22.0"

Within my __init__.py-file I then read the version via
from importlib import metadata
from typing import Any

try:
    import tomllib

    with open("pyproject.toml", "rb") as project_file:
        pyproject: dict[str, Any] = tomllib.load(project_file)
    __version__ = pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
except Exception as _:
    __version__: str = metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)

This works fine as long as I use this project as my main project. However, when exporting it into a wheel file (using poetry build) the pyproject.toml-file is not included.
When I then install the generated wheel-file in a separate project with similar structure and version information
[tool.poetry]
name = "Project B"
version = "1.0.0"

and try to read out the version of my initial package A via
import A
print(A.__version__)

I get 1.0.0, and not (as expected) 1.22.0.
Is there a way to "bake" the version into package A during wheel-file generation, to avoid such issues?

The easiest (and correct) way is simply not provide this, given that importlib.metadata will provide this through version for users that actually need this - refer to this answer.
